# Integrerate Spark Streaming and Kafka, but get bad symbolic reference error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to integrate Spark streaming and Kafka. I wrote my source code in intellij idea IDE; the complier compiled the code without any error, but when I try to build the jar file, an error message is generated that shows:

> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in KafkaUtils.class
>   refers to term kafka in package  which is not available. It may
>   be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
>   the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when
>   compiling KafkaUtils.class.

I did research on google, many people say this is because of different versions between Scala version and `spark_streaming_kafka` jar file. But I have checked the version, they are the same.

Does someone know why this error happened?

Here are more details:

scala version : 2.10 
spark streaming kafka jar version : spark_streaming_kafka_2.10-1.20.jar,spark_streaming_2.10-1.20.jar

My source code:

```
object Kafka { 

  def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    val master = "local[*]" 
    val zkQuorum = "localhost:2181" 
    val group = "" 
    val topics = "test" 
    val numThreads = 1 

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka") 
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2)) 

    val topicpMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap 

    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicpMap).map(_._2) 

    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")) 

    words.print() 

    ssc.start() 
    ssc.awaitTermination() 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I struggled with the same error. I don't remember the exact reason, but checkout [this example](https://github.com/mkrcah/scala-kafka-twitter) of Kafka-Scala integration. Works with Spark 1.2, Kafka 0.8.1.1 and Scala 2.10.